# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, build.gradle

tengo algunos problemas.

Estoy tratando de compilar la Aplicación para "release" desde Android Studio, la misma esta en Flutter.

Sin embargo tenía este error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> path may not be null or empty string. path='null'
```

lo arregle cambiando mi línea de código original en build.gradle de esta:

```
storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
```

A esta otra:

```
storeFile file("key.jks")
```

Pero ahora tengo este error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storePassword".
```

Yo de esto no se mucho, la app no se va a distribuir por medio de la PlayStore que puedo hacer, porque he leído sobre firmar y generar archivos y contraseñas pero no logro entender bien que es lo que debo hacer, espero me puedan hechar una mano.

Mi archivo buid.gradle

```
// For Onesignal Notifications

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        // OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.12.1, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

// For release APK or Bundle

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('nextrim.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()
    ndkVersion '22.0.7026061'
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "net.nextrim.go"
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    // For release APK or Bundle

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file("key.jks")
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.

            // For release APK or Bundle
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            // signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución, habia cambiado el nombre de un archivo .properties por nextrim.properties es por ello que no encontraba los parámetros necesarios. Restablecí el nombre y funciono.

```
// For release APK or Bundle

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('nexthour.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```